# Икона может иметь придел? Какая-нибудь сверхзначимая икона?

Tags: выбор-слов

> ПРИДЕЛ - в православном храме особый алтарь, отдельный от главного,
>   содержащий в себе все, что составляет принадлежность всякого алтаря,
>   т. е. престол и жертвенник с принадлежностями и пр. Подобно главному
>   алтарю, он отделяется от других частей храма…

В моём тексте:

> ...Среди наиболее известных его работ в Риме – скульптурное оформление
>   храма Сант-Аньезе-ин-Агоне и придел иконы Народная Мадонна / Madonna
>   Salus Populi Romani в базилике Санта-Мария-Маджоре.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, может.

Примеры употребления:

> 1. По благословению Владыки Сергия храм этот, построенный по древнерусским образцам из вековых сосен, будет иметь три придела: центральный — по названию храма, левый — во имя святого Преподобного Серафима Саровского, правый — во имя иконы Божией Матери «Умиление».
> 2. По главному престолу церковь носит название Преображенской, но из-за связанного с ней прославления иконы Божией Матери «Всех скорбящих Радость», в честь которой освящён один из приделов, известна под названием Скорбященской
> 3. Престолы: Главный — Спаса Преображения, приделы — иконы Божией Матери «Всех скорбящих Радость» и преподобного Варлаама Хутынского.

Comment: В примерах всё больше "в честь которой" да "во имя"... Так что остаётся боковой алтарь... Спасибо, будем думать.